# Matlab: Matrice -> how to store more than one value in one cell?

Tags: matlab

I have 2 matrices: inputdata1 and inputdata2. These 2 matrices have only 3 columns, but a different number of rows.
From these two matrices, I read the the first the second and the third column separate and write them on x y and z. The more matrices I have, the more columns i get (x y and z)
But I dont want this. No further columns i want.... I want one column but i also dont want to add it... I mean to add it at the end from the column before.

I want to create a kind of "register card" like in excel, or a cell where i can store more than one value.

This means that x should has always only one column, but several "pages" each additional page corresponds to the x of a new matrice ... If there is a solution.... What is the command for reading this values? I hope there is a solution. Thank you for your support. nice greedings

My Code (not that what i want):

```
inputdata1 = [ 3, 21, 7; 
12, 21,  7; 
3,  12,   7; 
12,  7,  7; 
3,  7,  7; 
12, 3,   7]; 

inputdata2= [ 923, 224911, 27; 
12, 21,  3247; 
3243,  132,   73; 
139242,  34327,  97; 
32433,  93247,  39247; 
9123924, 34233,   324237]; 



x(:,1) = inputdata1(:,1) 
y(:,1) = inputdata1(:,2) 
z(:,1) = inputdata1(:,3) 
x(:,2) = inputdata2(:,1) 
y(:,2) = inputdata2(:,2) 
z(:,2) = inputdata2(:,3)
```

Comment: Have you looked into cell arrays?

Comment: yes but i have no idea... i am quite new in matlab and no programmer.... :/

Comment: You'd just do `C = {inputdata1, inputdata2}` and then access them with `C{1}` and `C{2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want, but you could use

```
x{1} = inputdata1(:,1)
y{1} = inputdata1(:,2)
z{1} = inputdata1(:,3)

x{2} = inputdata2(:,1)
y{2} = inputdata2(:,2)
z{2} = inputdata2(:,3)
```

to avoid multiple columns and use cells which can be accessed like this e.g. for x:

```
>> x{1}
```

ans =

```
 3
12
 3
12
 3
12
```